# Convergence of composition of power series

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

I am doing a project, and I have to find an article/book/ something with a certain proof. It is about function/power series. My starting point is this:

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$$ with radius r>0

$$g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nz^n$$ with radius R>0

$$\lbrace g(z) : |z|<r \rbrace \subset D(0,r)$$

I have to prove that f o g (composition) has a power series expansion in a neighbourhood of zero, and say what we can say about the radius.

Also, I have to prove that analytic function composition is analytic, but I think I solved that using chain's rule and seeing that it is holomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $T$ small enough we have $\sum_n |b_n| |z|^n<r$ for $|z|<T$.

So that $$\sum_k |a_k| (\sum_n |b_n| |z|^n)^k$$ converges for $|z|<T$. The absolute convergence means that we can change the order of summation in $$f(g(z))=\sum_k a_k(\sum_n b_n z^n)^k=\sum_k a_k \sum_m B_{k,m} z^m=\sum_m z^m \sum_k a_k B_{k,m}$$
The same argument shows that for $G$ analytic on $U$ and $F$ analytic on $G(U)$ then $F(G(z))$ is analytic on $U$ (given by a power series around every point).